# Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSLayoutDimension' and 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I can't seem to figure this out, I've gone through all of the related questions however this is still niggling me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor * CGFloat(1.5)).isActive = true
```

I just need the height of this image to be 1.5x the width, and need to set it using constraints.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Use `constraint(equalTo:multiplier:)`:

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat(1.5)).isActive = true
```

Comment: Ahhh oh my god, so simple. Thanks so much!